# Install elementary OS 5.0 Juno on my elementary OS 0.4 Loki

Tags: system-installation, release-juno

I paid and then downloaded [release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno) to my laptop that is running [release-loki](/questions/tagged/release-loki). However I can't seem to install the ISO file.  Can someone tell me how to either burn the ISO file to DVD or CD on my laptop or how to mount the image file as a CDROM in order to execute. The file seems to be too big to move to a PC or MAC.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to follow the [installation instructions from the website](https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#creating-an-installation-medium).